# Show only from "name" not email address in JavaMailSender and client Outlook

Tags: java, email, outlook

I am using spring MimeMessageHelper and JavaMailSender. Is it possible to show only the message senders name and not the address when sending email , email client (Outlook).

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
// you can either do it this way with a regular string
message.setFrom("John Smith <john@example.com>");

// or this way with an InternetAddress
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("john@example.com", "John Smith"));
```